# Filtering through Many-to-Many returns only one association - Sequelize

Tags: sql, typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js, many-to-many

I have three related tables: `Product` and `Type` related by many-to-many and a join table `Product_Types`. My goal is to be able to include (and ideally count) `Product`s if they have a certain `Type` name, but also **including all their `Type`s**. Right now querying through the `Product` model (using Sequelize) returns the correct `Product`s but **with only the searched `Type`**. I've managed to make it work filtering through `Type`s but it's quite problematic for the actual state of my app.

Product:

```
@Table({tableName: 'products', timestamps: true})
@DefaultScope({
    include: [{model: Type, attributes: ['id', 'color']}],
})
export default class Product extends Model {
  @BelongsToMany(() => Type, () => ProductTypes)
  types: Type[];

  @Column({
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
  })
  id!: number;

  @Column({type: DataType.INTEGER})
  price: number;
}
```

Type:

```
@Table({tableName: 'types', timestamps: false, paranoid: false})
export default class Type extends Model {
  @BelongsToMany(() => Product, () => ProductTypes)
  products: Product[];

  @Column({
    type: DataType.UUID,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    unique: true,
  })
  id: string;

  @Column({type: DataType.STRING, unique: true})
  name: string;

  @Column({type: DataType.STRING})
  color: string;
}
```

Product_Types:

```
@Table({tableName: 'Product_Types'})
export default class ProductTypes extends Model {
  @ForeignKey(() => Product)
  productId: string;
  @BelongsTo(() => Product)
  product: Product;

  @ForeignKey(() => Type)
  typeId: string;
  @BelongsTo(() => Type)
  type: Type;
}
```

This is my service method:

```
getAll = async (
  {limit,offset,orderBy,search}: IFindAllOptions
) => {
  return Product.findAndCountAll({
      distinct: true,
      limit,
      offset,
      order: orderBy,
      include: [
        {
          model: Type,
          attributes: ['id', 'name', 'color'],
          ...(search.typeId && {where: {id: search.typeId}}),
        },
      ],
    });
}
```

The query generated by this code is as follows:

```
SELECT "Product".*,
       "types"."id"                      AS "types.id",
       "types"."name"                    AS "types.name",
       "types"."color"                   AS "types.color",
       "types->ProductTypes"."productid" AS "types.ProductTypes.productId",
       "types->ProductTypes"."typeid"    AS "types.ProductTypes.typeId"
FROM   (SELECT "Product"."ordernumber",
               "Product"."id",
               "Product"."price",
               "Product"."createdat",
               "Product"."updatedat"
        FROM   "products" AS "Product"
        WHERE  (SELECT "ProductTypes"."productid"
                FROM   "product_types" AS "ProductTypes"
                       INNER JOIN "types" AS "Type"
                               ON "ProductTypes"."typeid" = "Type"."id"
                                  AND
                       "Type"."id" = 'adasdasd-asdasasd-asdasd'
                WHERE  ( "Product"."id" = "ProductTypes"."productid" )
                LIMIT  1) IS NOT NULL
        LIMIT  6 offset 0) AS "Product"
       INNER JOIN ( "product_types" AS "types->ProductTypes"
                    INNER JOIN "types" AS "types"
                            ON "types"."id" = "types->ProductTypes"."typeid")
               ON "Product"."id" = "types->ProductTypes"."productid"
                  AND "types"."id" = 'asdasd-asdasd-asdasd'
ORDER  BY "types"."name" ASC;
```

As you can see, there is a `LIMIT 1` in the SELECT from the ProductTypes, which I don't know why it's there as I never explicitly added it.